# php pdo code to compare data from two table and return in result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables

**Table1**

Book  Receipt   Coupon

100   701       501,502

100   702       503,504

100   703       505,506

**Table2**

book1   receipt1 coupon1

100   701       501,502

100   702       503,504

I Am searching data from table1 based on bookno.

Now i need to check if i enter bookno = 100 and click search

then it check all receipt and coupon of table2...

and only return those value which is not present in table2.

**In above example**

**Below row is not present in table2 but present in table1**

100   703       505,506

**so query return only this row.....**

plz help me to do this...

```
<?php   
$receipt = "";
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid','root','');
if($_POST && isset($_POST['search']))
{       
    $result=$db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT receipt_no FROM scheme_master WHERE book_no2=:book_no2');
    $result->bindParam(':book_no2',$_POST['book_no']);
    $result->execute(); 
    $data1 = $result->fetchAll();
    $coupons = array(); 
        foreach($data1 as $row)
        {    
            $receipt[] = $row['receipt_no']; 

        }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the query might look like this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT master.receipt_no 
    FROM scheme_master AS master 
        JOIN book_issue_return  AS bir  ON master.bookno2 = bir.book_no 
 WHERE master.book_no2=:book_no2  AND (
    bir.receiptno  NOT IN 
        (SELECT master.receipt_no FROM scheme_master AS master ) AND 
    bir.couponno NOT IN (SELECT master.receiptno FROM scheme_master AS master ))
```

and then:

```
$data1 = $result->fetchAll();

if (count($data1)) {
    // return all the data
} else {
    // return message
}
```

Comment: but this return null value every time.. even value is not present in book_issue_return   table

Comment: i only need to check data of selected table is alredys exist in another table  if not than display data else display message....

Comment: I edited the query so it has a sub select that matches those rows where the receip and coupon are differents

Comment: but this shows error on query #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( SELECT * WHERE bir.receiptno != master.receipt_no OR bir.couponno != master.co' at line 3

Comment: I cant reproduce here the tables. but if you remove the select and leave the conditions it should work. SELECT DISTINCT master.receipt_no FROM scheme_master AS master 
JOIN book_issue_return  AS bir  ON master.bookno2 = bir.book_no 
 WHERE master.book_no2=:book_no2 AND ( bir.receiptno != master.receipt_no OR bir.couponno != master.coupon_no). Tell me if this worked

Comment: yes its working but data is not getting properly.....i said query select those data which is present in table1 but not present in table2...for ex there are 3 rows in table1 ..ok and out of this 3 rows 2rows are present in table2 ..then query select only 1 remaining row...

Comment: Is it returning all rows? What about change the OR to an AND?

Comment: this query is selecting all receipt and coupon which is present in table2 not matching both tables....

Comment: I have a textbox which echo value in edit mode but when i open this in edit mode and change search value from form then it display both edit value and search value also...<input type="text" name="receiptno" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $data['receiptno'];?><?php echo implode(',', $receipt); ?>" class="field size4" />

Comment: I will replicate the environment tomorrow, at work I don't have PHP or mysql

Answer (score 0):

I change query according to the requirement and its work for me..

```
SELECT DISTINCT SM.receipt_no FROM scheme_master AS SM
JOIN book_issue_return AS bir ON SM.book_no2 = bir.book_no
WHERE SM.book_no2 = :book_no2 AND (SM.receipt_no NOT IN (SELECT bir.receiptno FROM book_issue_return AS bir))
```